# Calling a function in my directive creates error: 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a service which returns a new generator. It's just a counter that starts from 0 and increments by one. I use it to set the attribute: `tabindex` in my HTML. But somehow I manage to change the `$scope`, which again renders my HTML, which again change the `$scope`, and so on (I guess this is what happens).

My service:

```
angular.module('someModule').service('TabIndexService', function () {
  this.newTabIndexGenerator = function () {
    function TabIndexGenerator() {
      this.currentIndex = 0;
      this.nextIndex = function () {
        return this.currentIndex++;
      };
    }
    return new TabIndexGenerator();
  };
});
```

My controller:

```
angular.module('anotherModule').controller('MyController', function (TabIndexService) {
  var tabIndexGenerator = TabIndexService.newTabIndexGenerator();
  $scope.nextTabIndex = function () {
    return tabIndexGenerator.nextIndex();
  };
});
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="/somehwere" tabindex="{{nextTabIndex()}}">This is a link</a>
<a href="/somehwere-else" tabindex="{{nextTabIndex()}}">This is another link</a>
```

And the error:

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

How is `{{nextTabIndex()}}` able to change the `$scope?`, what is really going on here?

Comment: wrap the `return new TabIndexGenerator()` in the `$scope.$evalAsync( [expression], [locals])`, [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more about $digest function and data binding.
Every time you bind an expression somewhere in your html template, angular will register a watcher ... a digest operation will loop through all watchers and will re-execute binded expression, then it will compare new value with the old one. If there is a difference between new and old value it will update the old value with new one. It will continue to loop through all watchers until it will not find differences, until any watcher will match his new and old value ... this means that on single $digest call a watcher's expression can be executed many times and compared with old value.

so, in your situation, every time when "nextTabIndex" function is executed it will return a different value and $digest will fall in a infinite loop because new value of valued expression will never match old one.

if you need a solution I will suggest to create a directive which will set tabindex attribute at element generation time.
like this:

```js
angular.module('anotherModule')
.controller('MyController', function (TabIndexService) {
  var tabIndexGenerator = TabIndexService.newTabIndexGenerator();
  $scope.nextTabIndex = function () {
    return tabIndexGenerator.nextIndex();
  };
})
.directive('tabindex', function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.attr('tabindex', scope.nextTabIndex());
    }
  }
})
```

and you html will look like this:

```html
<a href="/somehwere" tabindex="">This is a link</a>
<a href="/somehwere-else" tabindex="">This is another link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular execute $digest() until all bindings return oldValue===newValue for a max of 10 iterations. In your code you are using a function as binding (nextTabIndex()), so every $digest() angular call the function that return the incremented currentIndex, so oldValue is never equals to newValue.

change your code and use a scope variable for binding, use the increment funcion in same action like ng-click

Comment: Could you please provide an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of service is a singleton instance that will provide data / services to other controllers. In your current module, your service is reproducible. Instead of this service, create an object that per controller.
Or build a service like this:

```
var angularApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

angularApp.service('myService', function () {
   this.click = 0;

    this.callNext = function() {
     this.click++;   
    }
});

angularApp.controller('testCtrl',['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
   $scope.test = myService.click; 

    $scope.clickMe = function () {
        myService.callNext();
    }
}]);
```

In this way , you don't need to initial your service every time you call it.

Comment: Hmm, gives me the same error this code that you have here.